# Passing data from parent component to a child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-resource

I have a  parent component as follows

```
<template>
        <div class="row">
            <mappings mapping-list="{{currentMappings}}"></mappings>
        </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Mappings from './content/Mappings.vue';

    export default {
      data () {
       return {
         currentMappings: Array
       }
      },
      created () {
        this.readData();
      },
      methods: {
        readData () {
            this.$http.get('data/Books.xml').then((response)=> {
                var x2js = new X2JS();
                var jsonObj = x2js.xml_str2json( response.body );
                this.getMappings(jsonObj.WAStatus);
            });
        }, 
        getMappings (jsonObj) {
            this.currentMappings = jsonObj.WSSMappings;
        }
      },
      components: { Mappings }
    };
</script>
```

and a child "mappings" component as follows

```
<template>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="hpanel stats">
                <div class="panel-body h-200">
                    <div class="stats-title pull-left">
                        <h3>Mappings</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stats-icon pull-right">
                        <img src="images/mappings.png" class="browserLogo">

                    </div>
                    <div class="m-t-xl">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                                <tr v-for="mapping in mappingList ">
                                    <td>name - {{$index}}</td>
                                </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    Current WSS - SA Mappings
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            mappingList:Array
        },
        created () {
            console.log(this.mappingList);
            // console.log(this.$parent.mappings);
        }
    }
</script>
```

I am unable to pass data from the parent component to the child component. I am trying to use props here. The error that I am getting is

```
main.js:2756[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "mappingList". Expected Array, got String. (found in component: <mappings>)
```

**Update**
As per the  suggestions made I have updated the parent component as follows

```
<template>
        <div class="row">
            <browser-stats></browser-stats>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <mappings :mapping-list="currentMappings"></mappings>
        </div>
</template>

<script>

    import Mappings from './content/Mappings.vue';

    export default {
      data () {
       return {
         currentMappings: []
       }
      },
      created () {
        this.readData();
      },
      methods: {
        readData () {
            this.$http.get('data/WA_Status.xml').then((response)=> {
                var x2js = new X2JS();
                var jsonObj = x2js.xml_str2json( response.body );
                this.getMappings(jsonObj.WAStatus);
            });
        }, 
        getMappings (jsonObj) {
            this.currentMappings = jsonObj.WSSMappings;
         console.log(this.currentMappings.length);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.currentMappings));
        }
      },
      components: {  Mappings }
    };
</script>
```

and the child "mappings" component as follows

```
<template>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="hpanel stats">
                <div class="panel-body h-200">
                    <div class="stats-title pull-left">
                        <h3>Mappings</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stats-icon pull-right">
                        <img src="images/mappings.png" class="browserLogo">

                    </div>
                    <div class="m-t-xl">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                                <tr v-for="mapping in mappingList ">
                                    <td>{{mapping._name}}</td>
                                </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    Current WSS - SA Mappings
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            mappingList:[]
        }
    }
</script>
```

but I am getting an empty mappingList which means whenever I am doing `console.log(this.currentMappings.length);` I get undefined.. 
Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong here ?

Thanks

Comment: I have changed my answer due to your updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) Fist issue**

```
  data () {
   return {
     currentMappings: Array
   }
```

Should be

```
  data () {
   return {
     currentMappings: []
   }
```

**2) Second issue**

```
<mappings mapping-list="{{currentMappings}}"></mappings>
```

Should be:

```
<mappings :mapping-list="currentMappings"></mappings>
```

**3) Third issue**

```
    created () {
        console.log(this.mappingList);
        // console.log(this.$parent.mappings);
    }
```

This will return empty array every time. Because `mappingList` changed via AJAX and it's happed after `created()` was called. Try to use [`vue-devtool` (chrome plugin)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd) for better debug experience.

**UPDATED:**
To be able to watch async changes (like made with AJAX) consider to use `watch` this way:

```
{
   data(){ 
      //..
   },
   watch:{
      'currentMappings'(val){
          console.log('currentMappings updated', currentMappings);
      }
   }
}
```

Docs are [here](http://vuejs.org/api/#watch).

Comment: yes , i was encountering the same issue (empty array) .. Can you please suggest what I should do to overcome that ?

Comment: I got it working and i have marked your answer as the correct answer - thanks

Answer (score 1):

You use string interpolation (`{{ }}`) to try and pass the data to the prop - but the interpolation will turn the array into a string.

You should use a binding with `v-bind`

```
<mappings v-bind:mapping-list="currentMappings"></mappings>
...short form:
<mappings :mapping-list="currentMappings"></mappings>
```